# Oil radiator making sparks

Tags: electrical, heating, appliances

My oil-filled radiator emits sparks when the thermostat switches off. A loud click can be heard (this, I’ve seen, is normal) but when the room is dark I can see a spark through the slits in the casing around the thermostat.
Can anyone confirm if this is normal or dangerous? [image]

It doesn’t look very threatening, it doesn’t leave the body of the radiator, and it’s only one spark. But on the other hand it is a spark and I want to be safe

Comment: Cheap switches spark. It's not in itself dangerous, unless there's something in proximity to ignite.

Comment: I had a DeLonghi oil-filled that did this. Max power 2500 watts. Breaking a heavy load can cause a spark that you can see in a darkened room.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too concerned about the spark. A lot of switches spark a bit when turned off. You are breaking a 120V connection, and the current still wants to keep going as the switch contacts are separating. So it jumps the gap as long as it can and then (a fraction of a second later) the contacts are far enough apart that 120V is not enough to bridge the gap.

But *if possible*, I highly recommend a better type of heater. You are using a toaster to heat your room. Seriously. Almost any portable space heater in the US is a toaster with a fancy box. Sometimes "oil filled" (which it really is, but so what?), sometimes "ceramic", sometimes with a fan. Actually, the kind with a fan makes a lot of sense - call it a hair dryer instead of a toaster - because it actively pushes the 1,500W of heat farther out into the room. But they are all 1,500W of resistance heat, whether $20 or $100, whether a big name brand or one you've never heard of before.

There are two issues:

#### Efficiency

Electric resistance heat is generally the least efficient option available. Heat pumps are much more efficient for electric heat. Natural gas or propane is much more efficient (generally speaking) because it burns the fuel directly instead of burning it elsewhere to generate electricity (heat in the power plant is lost, in your house you are using almost all the heat directly because that's your goal).

So if you are able to do so, installing a better heating system (or improving the one you have, if most of the house gets warm enough but one or two rooms need supplemental heat) is a huge long-term improvement.

#### Safety

**[19 Dead After Space Heater Sparks NYC's Worst Fire Disaster in 30+ Years](https://www.nbcnewyork.com/news/local/31-people-seriously-injured-in-bronx-apartment-building-fire-fdny/3486866/)**

This is actually my bigger concern. Efficiency is "only money", and replacement with a more efficient heating may have a long (many years) payback time. But safety is another story.

Imagine putting a toaster on the floor underneath your hanging curtains and mashing the button down so that it is stuck on for an hour at a time. Sound crazy? People do that with electric space heaters all the time. Modern heaters do have a lot of safeguards built-in to automatically turn them off if they overheat or tip over. But fires can, *and do*, still happen. If you read the manual that comes with your space heater, you will find all kinds of warnings about unattended operation, distance from flammable items, safety around children, etc. Some people never read those manuals. Some people read them and think "whatever". Some people read them and try to be careful, *but a guest doesn't and moves things around, and the dog runs in, and clothes fall off a table onto a heater, and a child knocks a heater down, etc.* and fires do happen. The [NFPA report](https://www.nfpa.org/News-and-Research/Data-research-and-tools/US-Fire-Problem/Heating-equipment) includes:

- Over half (54%) of the home heating fire deaths were caused by having heating equipment too close to things that can burn, such as upholstered furniture, clothing, mattress, or bedding.
- A vast majority of home heating fire deaths (81%) involved stationary or portable space heaters.

Some of these are electric heaters, some are propane or other fuels. Obviously a heater that actually has a real flame inside adds additional concerns. I certainly don't recommend swapping an electric space heater for a propane space heater - you don't actually solve the problem and you add a carbon monoxide problem to the mix!

But if you can't replace electric space heaters with central heating of some sort, then consider [baseboard electric heating](https://amzn.to/32kbVmg):

[image: baseboard heater]

They are the same efficiency (for better or worse) as a portable electric space heater. And there is still *some* risk. However, they generally don't have the same super-hot spots as space heaters because they are designed for continuous use (i.e., don't need to warm up a room in 30 minutes because they are cycling all day without having to worry about moving them around, plugging them in, etc.), are installed on the wall (so no cords to trip over), have a small surface area (so you're not tempted to put stuff down on top "because its there"), are installed on their own separate circuits (which does cost initially, and installation can cost more than the heaters themselves) which avoids overloading your regular circuits by turning on a space heater on the same circuit that is running your computer, etc.

Comment: These days, I'd go for heat pump over gas any day, because of world prices on power. Gas prices are outstripping electricity by more & more each year. Go heat pump; summer an aircon unit, winter it's a heater.

Comment: @Tetsujin I agree in general. The devil is in the details, and in power prices in a given location. My key points here are: resistance electric heat is the worst + if you have to use resistance electric heat, install heaters that are much safer than portables.

Comment: electric radiators cannot get hot enough to ignite anything. they are also 100% efficient, which is hard to beat if going by efficiency.

Comment: @dandavis They absolutely can get hot enough. Some types are more vulnerable than others, but they definitely can get hot enough. Remember: same heat as a toaster, just spread out more. As far as efficiency, yes they are 100% efficient. But, somehow, heat pumps are *more than 100% efficient*.

Comment: TBF, if you said "economical" instead of "efficient" you have a solid case. note there's a one-time thermal safety cut off on radiators that will kill power long before ignition temps, mandated decades before tip-over and newer safety features.  There's WAY more surface area on a radiator than a toaster's thin heating elements, so the same power produce much less rise over ambient considering (temp = (power/area)). I 100% agree about heat pumps, but they are used in different scenarios than heaters; you can't just pickup a heat pump to keep the guest bedroom warm...